# Snowflake table and generator functions does not give expected result

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, table-functions

I tried to create a simple SQL to track query_history usage, but got into trouble when creating my timeslots using the `table` and `generator` functions (the CTE named `x` below).

I got no results at all when limiting the query_history using my timeslots, so after a while I hardcoded an SQL to give the same result (the CTE named `y` below) and this works fine.

Why does not `x` work? As far as I can see `x` and `y` produce identical result?

To test the example first run the code as it is, this produces no result.
Then comment the line `x as timeslots` and un-comment the line `y as timeslots`, this will give the desired result.

```
with 
x as (
    select
        dateadd('min',seq4()*10,dateadd('min',-60,current_timestamp())) f,
        dateadd('min',(seq4()+1)*10,dateadd('min',-60,current_timestamp())) t
    from table(generator(rowcount => 6))
), 
y as (
    select
        dateadd('min',n*10,dateadd('min',-60,current_timestamp())) f,
        dateadd('min',(n+1)*10,dateadd('min',-60,current_timestamp())) t
    from (select 0 n union all select 1 n union all select 2 union all select 3 
          union all select 4 union all select 5)
)

--select * from x;
--select * from y;

select distinct 
    user_name,
    timeslots.f
from snowflake.account_usage.query_history, 
   x as timeslots
   --y as timeslots
where start_time >= timeslots.f
and start_time < timeslots.t
order by timeslots.f desc;
```

(I know the code is not optimal, this is only meant to illustrate the problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SEQ](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/seq1.html):

> Returns a sequence of monotonically increasing integers, with wrap-around. Wrap-around occurs after the largest representable integer of the integer width (1, 2, 4, or 8 byte).
>
> If a fully ordered, gap-free sequence is required, consider using the ROW_NUMBER window function.

For:

```
with x as (
    select
        dateadd('min',seq4()*10,dateadd('min',-60,current_timestamp())) f,
        dateadd('min',(seq4()+1)*10,dateadd('min',-60,current_timestamp())) t
    from table(generator(rowcount => 6))
)
SELECT * FROM x;
```

Should be:

```
with x as (
    select
        (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY seq4())) - 1 AS n,
        dateadd('min',n*10,dateadd('min',-60,current_timestamp())) f,
        dateadd('min',(n+1)*10,dateadd('min',-60,current_timestamp())) t
    from table(generator(rowcount => 6))
)
SELECT * FROM x;
```